# Get two strings of text on the same line?

Tags: python, string, text

and sorry for the terrible title! I had no idea what to write, without making the tile 500 words long.

Let's say I have

```
print 'Hi!'
print 'How are you?'
```

Is there any way I can get this into the same line? "Hi! How are you?"

Here is the codes I am currently using:

```
choice = raw_input('>: ')
if choice=='1':
    menu1()
else:
    print '' +choice
    print 'is not a recognized commando.'
```

The other code I have is:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print
print 'Now chatting with Tom'
time.sleep(2)
print
print
print(Fore.RED + 'Tom >: ') + print(Fore.GREEN + 'test')
```

Of course this didn't work. I just wanted to test.

Is there any way I can get these two string into the same line?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

Thank you very much everyone! I know the most basic parts of Python, but I have no idea how I could ignore the **,**

Anyway. For some reason I get extra spaces. I want to write [12:41:39] (time). In my code, it looks like this:

```
print(Fore.YELLOW + '['),
print strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
print ']          ',
```

And the output is [ 12:41:39 ]

I have no idea what's wrong here. I really hope someone here could explain this for me! Thank you!

Comment: You are on Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks like he's using Python 2.x since his `print`s don't have parentheses.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 It just feels more confortable to work with than Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2.x, where [`print` is a statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement), add a trailing comma:

```
print 'Hi!',  # No newline will be printed
```

In Python 3.x, where [`print()` is an ordinary function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) instead of a statement, pass an empty string for the `end` keyword parameter:

```
print('Hi!', end='')
```

If you use the `from __future__ import print_function` in Python 2.x code for forwards compatibility, then you'll need to use the function version instead of the statement version.

Comment: Thank you for the information! As thegrinner is saying, I am using Python 2.7 as I feel it's more confortable than 3.

For some reason when I do this, I get extra spaces. I have updated my post where you can see my new code, and hopefully find out what's wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use trailing comma, which will suppress the newlines added after `print`. Check out [`print` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

```
print 'Hi!',
print 'How are you?'
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a comma at the end of the statement:

```
print 'Hi!',
print 'How are you?'
```

Output:

```
Hi! How are you?
```

This is from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

> A `'\n'` character is written at the end, **unless the `print` statement ends with a comma**.

Answer (score 2):

In python 2.x you can use a comma after the `print` statement

```
print 'Hi!',
print 'How are you?'
```

which will output:

```
Hi! How are you?
```

You can also import the `print` function from python 3.x and do

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("Hi!", end='')
```

This puts an empty string as the ending character **instead** of a `\n`

Answer (score 2):

Use a comma:

`print 'Hi!', 'How are you?'`

Answer (score 1):

In Python3:

```
print('text', end='')
print('text', end='')
```

Is what you are looking for I guess! : `texttext`

You can also set the separator:

```
print('text', 'text', 'text', sep = '')
```

Gives: `texttexttext` instead of `text text text`

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks like he's using Python 2.x since his `print`s don't have parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You can also put all your string in one string like that :

```
>>> string = 'abc' + 'def'
>>> print string
'abcdef'
```